# How to call MS Project API

Tags: ms-project

I need to write a macro to reschedule multiple projects. I am able to do everything, except I am not able to perform actions exactly same as in-built Reschedule option does. Is there someway that I can use or run in-built functions like using API or something? I hope my idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

To do these actions in VBA, use the [UpdateProject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.updateproject) method of the MS Project [Application object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application).

[image]

See also: [UpdateTasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.updatetasks), [RescheduleToNextAvailable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.rescheduletonextavailable).

Comment: hi Rachel, I tried that but that is not producing exact sames dates as are produced by using built-in option, though the error rate is very less like 16 out of 17k tasks, 6 out 4k tasks

Comment: Do you have any idea of above problem?

Comment: No, I don’t know.